# Static scheduling priorities with 40 CPU cores?

Tags: c, scheduling

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    while( i < 20 )
    {
        if( fork() == 0 )
        {
            setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS,0,i);
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while( i <= 0.9*INT_MAX )
        i++;

    int p = getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS,0);
    printf("priority %d\n", p);

    while( wait(NULL) != -1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
priority 10
priority 12
priority 16
priority 14
priority 6
priority 3
priority 15
priority 8
priority 5
priority 1
priority 4
priority 0
priority 2
priority 18
priority 7
priority 17
priority 19
priority 9
priority 13
priority 11
```

This output is generated by the main(), I'm not able to find why I'm getting this output even though the processes have a particular pattern of static scheduling priorities and have 40 CPU cores?

Also, the 2nd wile loop `while( i <= 0.9*INT_MAX )` is it acting like a timer function or random function?

Comment: Only 20 processes?  Shoud there not be a whole lot more?

Comment: testing on 20 for now

Comment: If you have more cores than processes, they can all run whenever the want to no matter what priority they have.

Comment: @MartinJames I guess Parent is same for all the child and it will stop creating more child once 20 process get created?

Comment: @BoPersson do you mean processes can run on any core randomly? is `while( i <= 0.9*INT_MAX )` helping to do that?

Comment: @June - Process priority will have an effect when the processes have to wait in line to get an execution slot. But if there are free cores available, each process can just run at full speed and there will be no waiting. Having a VIP card (prio 1) is no advantage if you are the only one trying to get into the club.

Comment: @BoPersson thank you, but what is `while( i <= 0.9*INT_MAX )` doing?

Comment: Unclear. Maybe you should learn first with 1 core?

Comment: @June - The `while( i <= 0.9*INT_MAX ) i++;` is just incrementing `i` about 2 billion times, so the process has something to do. Otherwise it would get to the end immediately.